# ajax call not updating content on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to implement a bit a Ajax into my app seems to work correctly but it isnt updating the page after the action is executed .

I added Ajax to my Destroy method

```
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.user = current_user
    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Item Completed"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Item was unable to be marked completed "
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

i have update my _item.html.erb and _form.html.erb partials with `remote: true`

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'media', id: "item-#{item.id}" do %>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <small>
      <%= item.name.titleize %>
      | submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %>
      <% if current_user == @user %>
      <%= link_to "Completed ", [@user, item], method: :delete,remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %><br>
      <% end %>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

_from.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@user, item ], remote: true do |f|%>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name , class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a new item " %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Item", class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
<% end %>


User#show view <div class='new_item'>
<%= render :partial => 'items/form', :locals =>{:item => Item.new} %>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class='js-items'>
<% @user.items.order('created_at DESC').each do |item| %>
<%= render :partial => 'items/item' , :locals => {:item => item } %>
</div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#item-<%= @item.id %>').hide();
```

Like I said before, the item is deleted when i click the delete button but i need to refresh the page in order to see the updated page. Any ideas what i might be doing wrong, any push to the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to refresh the page? or you need to reload just the page content via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rendering the java script in the method itself and check,

```
def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.user = current_user
    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Item Completed"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Item was unable to be marked completed "
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render             
          $('#item-<%= @item.id %>').hide();
        }
    end
  end
```